# Extracting data from web table using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, html-table, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to extract data from a table using beautiful soup.
Its shows the data for the first line of data from the table then throws an error.

Is there any way to fix this?

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://libgen.io/search.php?mode=last')
print(r.text[0:500])
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.find_all('table')[2]:
try:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print(tds[0].text,tds[1].text,tds[2].text)
except NavigableString: 
    pass
```

Comment: `NavigableString` is not an exception type. If you're trying to catch `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'` you can use `AttributeError`

Comment: Thanks code is working.

Comment: As a side note: if you want to use `NavigableString` in the program somewhere, you'll have to first import it using `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString`.